# HTML form submit button not working. PHP programming

Tags: php, html

THis is a form for uploading a book. The Submit button is not active.
Please help. The form is sent via POST and to a file called upload.php
There are two divisions: main and body
body is further divided into 
header
bodylop
footer
bodylop is further divided into
body1
body2
body3

The form is in body1
When i take my cursor above the submit button, then it does not show http://localhost/Booksharing/upload.php

When i click it
Nothing Happens

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http:/www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Uploading Book</title>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="stylesheets/style2.css" title="Default Styles" media="screen">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class= 'main'>
    <div class = 'headlop'>
    <?php
    include ('header.php');
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class = 'body'>

    <div class = 'bodylop'>
    <div style="position:absolute; margin-left:5%; top:4%; height:50%; width:50%;">
    <table width="90%" height="80%" border="5">
    <form method="post" action="upload.php">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2"> <center> BOOK DETAILS </center>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Name
    <td> <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="50" name="bName" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Author
    <td> <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="50" name="author" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Type
    <td> <select name="type">
                 <option value="Newsletter">Newsletter</option>
                 <option value="Course Book">Course Book</option>
                 <option value="Reference Book">Reference Book</  option> 
                 <option value="Magazine">Magazine</option>
                 <option value="Novel">Novel</option> 
                 <option value="Journal">Journal</option> 

            </select>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> Genre
  <td> <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" name="genre" />
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> Condition
 <td> <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="50" name="cond" />
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> Price
 <td> <input type="int" size="40" maxlength="50" name="price" />
 </tr> 
 <tr>
 <td> Origin
 <td> <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="50" name="orig" />
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> Tags
 <td> <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="50" name="tags" />
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan='2' align="center"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
 </tr>
 </form>
 </table>
 </div>
 <div style="
  margin-left:5%; top:50%; height:50%; width:50%;  position:absolute;">
 </br>
 </br>
 </br>
 <A HREF = "publish.php">Upload/Publish</A> </br>
        <A HREF = "others.php">View What others have posted </A> </br>

 </div>
 <div style="position:absolute; margin-left:50%; top:0%; height:100%; width:50%;  size:8px; padding:1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm;">


 </div>
 </div>
 <div class = 'footlop'">
 <?php include('footer1.php'); ?>
 </div>
```

`

Answer (score 3):

this DIV is coming over the Submit Button

```
<div style="
  margin-left:5%; top:50%; height:50%; width:50%;  position:absolute;">
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <a href="publish.php">Upload/Publish</a> <br>
        <a href="others.php">View What others have posted </a> <br>
 </div>
```

Avoid Using Absolute Position, Or use firebug to inspect elements in such cases, it will highlight them.